# Plotting financial data

Tags: c++, qt, plot, gnuplot, financial

I'm implementing some simple machine learning algorithms on some financial data in c++, and would like to be able to present this in a 'professionel' way to a potential customer.

Does anyone know a good framework for displaying financial charts?

Or is there a simple way to do something else like embed gnuplot in a qt widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your customer is in finance, speak to them on their terms. Financial people do things in Excel and Powerpoint. Write your data in comma-separated value format, import this into Excel, create some Excel plots, and pull this into a Powerpoint presentation.

You might think of Excel and Powerpoint as being beneath someone who can develop machine learning techniques. Don't think that way. You are trying to sell a product, you need to speak in the customer's lingo, not your's.

And do check for spelling errors in your presentation. 'Professionel' presentations do not have misspelled words.

Comment: yep, even if I find Excel charts ugly and absolutely unflexible, they "look" professional, by the very definition of professional.

Comment: If you go the Excel route, see here http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~ahazel/EXCEL_C++.pdf for a guide to interfacing C++ programs with Excel.